# MySQL foreign key ON DELETE SET NULL check data types error

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I'm working on a normalised database, to be secure I wanted to use foreign keys.

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `name_2` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_id` (`name_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The command:

```
ALTER TABLE  `names` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `name` ) REFERENCES  `temp`.`users` (
`name_id`
) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

The response (error):
Error creating foreign key on name (check data types)

So, how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should also create your AUTO_INCREMENT columns unsigned you dont negative numbers there and also name_id if you dont need a negative value there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. `Name` in `names` table is of type `varchar(250)` whereas `name_id` in `users` table is of type `int(11)`.

But I believe you meant to have an FK all the way around in `users` table referencing `names` table.

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD FOREIGN KEY (name_id) REFERENCES names (id) 
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fffa)** demo

Comment: Wow, thanks! I guess a dumb mistake, I thought the DELETE and UPDATE were meant for when the parent changes, not the child. (parents = users, child = names).

Answer (score 0):

Both keys have to be the same type and length,you have varchar and int.

Here is what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE  `names` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `id` ) REFERENCES  `users` (
`name_id`)
```

Comment: They both have INT(11) set as their type?

Comment: Name and name_id are different.

Comment: True, but am I not creating a relation between `names`.`id` and `users`.`name_id`?

Comment: No,you are creating a relation between names.name adn users.name_id.